# Django page not found with include pattern

Tags: django

I have a question related to django and the urls.py files.
I have created a small program coming from openclassroom during the tutorial. 
I have been able to set the URL properly in the projectname folder/urls.py to make it work. Now I want to put the URL in the app folder and refer to them in the project name folder/urls.py but when I try to use the page, it tells me that it does not exist.
I am using python 3.4 and django 1.9.7.
The program is called creps_bretonnes.

my creps_bretonnes/urls.py:(I have tried the different version of urlpatterns without success)

```
 from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from blog import views
"""
urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'^accueil$', views.home),
    # url(r'^blog/', 'blog.urls'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

]
"""
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
)
```

my blog.urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from . import views

#urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
#    url(r'^accueil$', 'home'),
#)
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accueil$', views.home),
]
```

This is the message that I get from the page http://localhost:8000/blog/accueil/

Page not found (404)

Request Method: GET

Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/blog/accueil/

Using the URLconf defined in creps_bretonnes.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

1. ^blog/ ^accueil$

The current URL, blog/accueil/, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

I am stuck here and do not know how to continue. Can someone please help?

Thanks,
SP

Answer (score 0):

You tried the url `http://localhost:8000/blog/accueil` (without a trailing slash), but your url pattern is `^accueil$` (without a trailing slash).

You can either change the url pattern to:

```
url(r'^accueil/$', views.home),
```

Or you can access the existing url pattern at `http://localhost:8000/blog/accueil`.

With Django, it is more common to include a trailing slash in the url patterns, so I recommend the first approach.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your help. Just to understand, it is actually the same url pattern. Why is it interpreted differently then?

Comment: It isn't interpreted differently. If you use `url(r'^accueil/$', views.home),` inside `creps_bretonnes/urls.py`, then `http://localhost:8000/accueil` will work, but `http://localhost:8000/accueil/` will give a similar 404 error.